# How to loop through dictionary objects in rust?

Tags: loops, dictionary, rust, hashmap

I have a dictionary which in python I can iterate using

```
data = {"one":1,"two":2,"three":3,"four":4,....."two hundred":200}

for i,j in data.items():
    print(i,j)
```

Is there any way I can use the same object and iterate over the keys and values in rust?

Comment: `for (i, j) in data` (`i` and `j` are owned values) or `for (r, s) in &data` (`r` and `s` are references)

Comment: Are you asking about Rust syntax for the same thing? Or by "same object" do you mean accessing the Python object from Rust using PyO3 or something?

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming you're after a way to do this in Rust.

Rust's analogue to a Python dictionary is a `HashMap`.

Unlike Python's dictionaries `HashMap`s are statically typed (i.e. all the keys must have the same type, and all the values must also share the same type) – to create a new `HashMap` you want something like:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
  let mut hashmap: HashMap<String, i32> = HashMap::new();
  hashmap.insert("one".to_string(), 1);
  for (key, value) in hashmap {
      println!("{} {}", key, value);
  }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
one 1
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3a0ad6345606f44c727016d970acc90d)

If you want to load the object from Python into Rust, there are a couple of options

- You can serialize the object in the Python process and then use [`serde`](https://serde.rs) to deserialize it on the Rust side.
- You can bind to CPython (e.g. using PyO3).

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
use serde_json::json;

fn main() {
          
    let data = json!({"one":1,"two":2,"three":3,"four":4});    

    for (key, value) in data.as_object().unwrap(){
        println!("{:?} : {:?}",key,value.as_u64().unwrap());
    }
}
```

Comment: However, HashMap is a direct replacement of a Dicts from Puthon, your solution looks most "pythonic" analog to what dicts feels in Python. Thx!